# OAuth PHP, scope=messages

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, oauth

PHP код:

```
<?php 
session_start(); // Токен будем хранить в сессии


// Выводим на экран ссылку для открытия окна диалога авторизации


$clientId     = ''; // ID приложения
$clientSecret = ''; // Защищённый ключ
$redirectUri  = ''; // Адрес, на который будет переадресован пользователь после прохождения авторизации



// Формируем ссылку для авторизации
$params = array(
    'client_id'     => $clientId,
    'redirect_uri'  => $redirectUri,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'v'             => '5.74', // (обязательный параметр) версия API, которую Вы используете https://vk.com/dev/versions

    // Права доступа приложения
    // Если указать "offline", полученный access_token будет "вечным" (токен умрёт, если пользователь сменит свой пароль или удалит приложение).
    // Если не указать "offline", то полученный токен будет жить 12 часов.
    'scope'         => '140491999',
);

// Выводим на экран ссылку для открытия окна диалога авторизации
echo '<a href="http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?' . urldecode(http_build_query( $params )) . '">Авторизация через ВКонтакте</a>';


if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $params = array(
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
        'v'    => '5.74',
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
    );

    $token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);
    echo $token;
}
?>
```

Получаю:

`{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"standalone applications should use blank.html as redirect_uri to access messages"}`

Сама ошибка то понятна, но всё равно вопрос:
***Как получить access на сообщения итд через php?***

Поясните, кому не трудно, а то я туплю.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При регистрации вами приложения в платформе ВК для разработчиков, вы указали тип - standalone, вместо веб сайт.

Посадочная страница для standalone всегда фиксированная - blank.html, сделанно это потому что standalone приложения получают access_token самостоятельно, веб-сайт на сервере.

Зарегистрируй приложение с типом веб-сайт, и у тебя все получиться.

Советую на будущее использовать библиотеки для авториции, к примеру:

https://github.com/socialconnect/auth